# Setting up password only authentication in apache

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

I have a folder on my website using apache basic authentication.
The Auth is controlled by a .htaccess file which has been placed into the directory that should be protected.

This is the content of the .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please enter your credentials to continue."
AuthUserFile /my/path/here/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

However, I do not want to give every person that is using the protected directory their own credentials, I would like them all to share a single secret.

Is it possible to stop apache from asking for a user name *and* a password and instead only asking for a password, using only a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible using Basic Authentication. It's not Apache that asks for username and password; it's the browser.

Apache only sends [a generic header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Server_side):

> WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm"